# why does StrToDateTime is throwing exception

Tags: delphi

My system date time format is "dd-MM-yy". And in my db the date is stored like "04/12/12" when i try to convert the string to date using the following code i am getting exception

```
formatSettings := TFormatSettings.Create(LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT);
Result := StrToDateTime(sDateTime, formatSettings);
```

when i examined the format settings the ShortDateFormat is "dd/MM/yy" and the DateSeparator is coming as "-" but when i hard code my dateseperator to "/" it is working fine but is that the correct approach?

Comment: I'm not surprised: "04/12/12" is an extremely pathological format for a date.

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly fine to change format settings. But declare your own, separate variable for that. Don't modify the global `FormatSettings` variable given to you by Delphi for this purpose.

Comment: is there anyway we can pickup the dateseperator dynamically? and my confusion is mainly when my system format is dd-mm-yy how come the formatsettings date format is wrong and dateseperator is correct?

Comment: why do you think it is wrong ? it only means someone stored dates into your database as-string instead of as-date, and he used tat weird exotic format for this, it does tell nothing about settings of your OS or Delphi RTL